# How to map a log file in Java using Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have to monitor a log file in which is written the history of utilization of an app. This log file is formatted in this way:

```
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
<AppId,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
... about 800000 rows
```

`AppId` is always the same, because is referenced at only one app, `date` is expressed in this format `dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm` `cpuUsage` and `memoryUsage` are expressed in `%` so for example:

```
<3ghffh3t482age20304,230720142245,0.2,3,5>
```

To be specific, I have to check the percentage of CPU usage and memory usage by this application to be monitored using spark and the map reduce algorithm.

**My output is to print alert when the cpu or the memory are 100% of usage**.

How can I start?

Comment: what is your intended output? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ayanguha see updates.

Comment: Are new logs appended to the same log file? Or you have some logging rolling strategy?

Comment: Assuming your log data is realtime generating logs. use flume and spark streaming to do alerting .  i.e., : apache-tomcat-logs > flume > spark-streaming

Comment: there is no new logs appended for now. But in future will be in real-time.

Comment: @ramisetty.vijay ok, i'm viewing spark streaming. But my problem is, how i can map this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to declare a class and map the line into a scala object,

Lets declare the case class as follows,

```
case class App(name: String, date: String, cpuUsage: Double, memoryusage: Double)
```

Then initialize the SparkContext and create a RDD from the text file where the data is present,

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val inFile = sc.textFile("log.txt")
```

then parse each line and map it to App object so that the range checking would be faster,

```
val mappedLines = inFile.map(x => (x.split(",")(0), parse(x)))
```

where the parse(x) method is defined as follows,

```
 def parse(x: String):App = {
   val splitArr = x.split(",");
   val app = new App(splitArr(0),
                      splitArr(1),
                      splitArr(2).toDouble,
                      splitArr(3).toDouble)
   return app
}
```

Note that i have assumed the input as follows, (this is just to give you the idea and not the entire program),

```
ffh3t482age20304,230720142245,0.2,100.5
```

Then do the filter transformation where you can perform the check and report the anamoly conditions,

```
val anamolyLines = mappedLines.filter(doCheckCPUAndMemoryUtilization)
anamolyLines.count()
```

where doCheckCPUAndMemoryUtilization function is defined as follows,

```
def doCheckCPUAndMemoryUtilization(x:(String, App)):Boolean = {
    if(x._2.cpuUsage >= 100.0 ||
       x._2.memoryusage >= 100.0) {
       System.out.println("App name -> "+x._2.name +" exceed the limit")
       return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Note: This is only a batch processing and not real-time processing.